# How to remove special characters from URL in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a value from `URL`. The problem is, it may have some special characters in it and I want to remove that. Meaning, `http://localhost/DoSomething/Index/123#` is my `URL`. I can get `123#`, now I want to remove `#` from it.

Example:

URL = http://localhost/DoSomething/Index/123#

Result = 123#

Expected Result = 123

```js
 var sPageUrl = "http://localhost/DoSomething/Index/123#";
 var number = sPageUrl.substring(sPageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 alert(number);
```

Comment: I thought C# also has regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into

```
 var sPageUrl = "http://localhost/DoSomething/Index/123#";
 var number = sPageUrl.substring(sPageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
 alert(number);
```

You could use regex to strip all special characters from the string

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I would consider for this.

1. Strip off the `#` and everything that follows.

   ```
   var number = sPageUrl.substring(0, sPageUrl.indexOf('#'));
   alert(number);
   ```
2. Split on the `#` so you have that information when you want it.

   ```
   var number = sPageUrl.split('#'),
       url,
       hash;

   if (number.length > 1) {
       url = number[0];
       hash = number[1];
   }
   alert(url);
   ```

Bonus: Both of these approaches also work well for dealing with QueryStrings.